# Interactive logon: Do not display last user name doesn't work

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm trying to stop user from knowing who's online before a successful login, I already have `Interactive logon: Do not display last user name` enabled in GPO, but I can still see users that's logged in.

(I disabled NLA, since I run Linux desktop and connect with `rdesktop` command)

Comment: Sorry, but what does NLA have to do with you running a Linux Desktop.  I think you are omitting some details here.  If you are running a Linux desktop, what are you talking about?

Comment: @Zoredache - I believe he's referring to his 2k8 server, the part about NLA and his linux desktop is irrelevant unless I am reading it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to 2008 R2, you can use the following:

On your servers, please open RD Session Host Configuration (tsconfig.msc), double-click RDP-Tcp.  On the Log on Settings tab, select Always use the following log on information, and enter your domain in the domain box.

After making the above change please test that the username does not appear when you connect using Remote Desktop.

The behavior you are seeing is the default, even in older versions (2008, 2003, etc.). The RD Client will send the last user name to the server, and it will appear on the logon screen.  If there is no last user name it will send the current local user name.

One thing to note if you use the technique I outlined above is that logon using credentials entered at the client will no longer work.  The user will always be prompted at the server logon screen.

CREDIT: TP (moderator on Technet forums and MVP)